# React — display field but get object

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have an object `Category`, which has two fields: `name` and `description`.

I want to display a dropdown, where the user is shown the `description` of all categories. However, descriptions are not unique so I would like to get the object selected by the user instead of its description.

I want to do something like this:

```js
handleSelect: function(event){
   // Here, I would like to get the Category selected, not the description!!!
},

render: function(){

    var categoryDesc = this.props.categories.map(function(elem){
        return <option><a href="#">{elem.description}</a></option>
    });

    return(
        <div>
            <p>Select category</p>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <select class="form-control" onChange={this.handleSelect}>
                    {categoryDesc}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `index` in `map` you can save that as the value for each `option` then use it to get the correct item from `props.categories`.

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
handleSelect: function(index){
    console.log(this.props.categories[index]); // element with name and description
},
render: function(){
    var categoryDesc = this.props.categories.map(function(elem, index){
        return (
            <option class="form-control" value={index}>
                {elem.description}
            </option>
        );
    });

    return(
        <div>
            <p>Select category</p>
            <select onChange={this.handleSelect}>
                {categoryDesc}
            </select>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: you are creating multiple select here。。。。

Comment: I doubt there is onChange event on option。。。。

Comment: I was too quick with my answer and attempt to understand the question. You're right again